# How to use connection string when invoking pg_recvlogical?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build some automation that uses `pg_recvlogical` and I can't seem to figure out how to use a full connection string to bypass the password prompt. I've several variations like

```
 pg_recvlogical postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db.cluster-cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky --slot migration_goldsky --start -f file.sql
```

But I keep getting the following errors

```
pg_recvlogical: error: too many command-line arguments (first is "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db.cluster-cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky")
Try "pg_recvlogical --help" for more information.
```

Is there a way to use `pg_recvlogical` with a full connection string similar to psql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pg_recvlogical does not treat its first positional argument as the database name/connection string, the way psql does.  You need to make the -d switch explicit:

```
pg_recvlogical -d postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db.cluster-cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky --slot migration_goldsky --start -f file.sql
```